# How to allign labels in one div and corresponding textboxes in other?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to make responsive site in which labels in one div and corresponding text box in other. I have written a small piece of code.Its working(for md device) but when window size is resized its format is not correct(Both labels are clubbed together).How to correct this (for xs devices)? PFB the screenshot.
[image: sample.bmp]

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <form role="form">


            <div class="row">
              <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" for="TextArea">Text Area</label>
              <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" for="TextArea">Text Area</label>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea"></textarea>
              </div>                  
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your labels inside each `div` containing the `textarea` tag.

```
<form role="form">            
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <label for="TextArea1">Text Area</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea1"></textarea>
     </div>                            
     <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
       <label for="TextArea2">Text Area</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea2"></textarea>
    </div>                  
  </div>
</form>
```

[Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qqstv3w/2/) (slide JSFiddles vertical axis to simulate the environment size you need)

Comment: BTW, I just copied your code and change it a little bit. But I didn't notice you got items with the same ID. I know it's a example, but you should know not to have identical IDs.

Comment: ya i know ... just for testing  :)